# API Blueprint parameter name not displaying

Tags: atom-editor, apiblueprint

I am new to API Blueprint so please excuse my naivety here.  I am trying to format some parameters such as given in the Aglio example:

```
+ Parameters

    + name (optional, string, `alice`) ... Search for a user by name
    + joinedBefore (optional, string, `2011-01-01`) ... Search by join date
    + joinedAfter (optional, string, `2011-01-01`) ... Search by join date
```

However, all that is displaying for the name of the parameter is the index of the parameter.  Here is the display from the Atom API-Display package: https://atom.io/packages/api-blueprint-preview.

[image]

How can I make it display the name of the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of blueprint looks OK. Just for the sake - can you share the URI template used to defined the respective resource? The URI template should contain something like this:

```
{?name,joinedBefore,joinedAfter}
```

e.g.

```
# Resource [/resource{?name,joinedBefore,joinedAfter}]
```

But again the blueprint looks OK so it might be a problem with Aglio or the preview package itself. Best to check and report at https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio/issues?state=open or https://github.com/danielgtaylor/atom-api-blueprint-preview/issues.

Comment: not sure how to show the URI template, how can I find it?

Comment: what you mea by "to show" – the URI Template is part of the resource section definition – https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-resource-section